# How to check if a color is out of gamut of a color space

Tags: color-conversion, gamut

I'm developing a canvas web application converting colors of an image from Display P3 to sRGB using the [relative colorimetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management#relative_colorimetric) gamut mapping algorithm (in-gamut colors are rounded/aligned, out-of-gamut colors are clamped).

Before actual conversion, I need to have a preview figuring out which colors will be out-of-gamut and showing those out-of-gamut pixels with a fallback color (like black or cyan).

So the process blocked here:

```
function isOutOfGamut(colorXYZ, colorSpaceInfo){
  // TODO
}
```

- `colorXYZ` is a color described in CIE XYZ
- `colorSpaceInfo` contains all information about a color space, can be extracted from some ICC color profile

Comment: This problem seems to be quite complex, I break it into three parts.
part 1: extract color space info (whitepoint, primary colors, OETF, ...) from an ICC profile,
part 2: build a 3D geometry for the color space,
part 3: check if a point is inside the 3D geometry.